# Can anyone help me understand this asm code (It's short)

Tags: security, debugging, assembly, segmentation-fault, debian

I'm trying to learn shellcode for a project
in comp science

but I’m having a bit of a problem writing it
I’m reading a book called The Shellcoder's Handbook
and it gives me a code that wont work properly
This is the code:

```
    section     .text
    global _start
_start:
    jmp short      GotoCall
shellcode:
     pop            rsi
     xor            rax, rax
     mov  byte      [rsi + 7], al
     lea            rbx, [rsi]
     mov            [rsi + 8], rbx
     mov            [rsi + 14], rax
     mov  byte      al, 0x0b
     mov            rbx, rsi
     lea            rcx, [rsi + 8]
     lea            rdx, [rsi + 14]
     int            0x80
GotoCall:
     Call            shellcode
     db             '/bin/shJAAAAAAKKKKKK'
```

simply put this is supposed to spawn a shell...
but it wont work and when i use gdb to debug it
i get a weird code and a segmentation fault error at

```
mov  byte      [rsi + 7], al
```

this is the gdb output:
gdb ./sclivro

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400085 in _start ()
(gdb) disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
0x0000000000400080 <_start+0>:  jmp    0x4000a2 <_start+34>
0x0000000000400082 <_start+2>:  pop    %rsi
0x0000000000400083 <_start+3>:  xor    %rax,%rax
0x0000000000400085 <_start+5>:  mov    %al,0x7(%rsi)
0x0000000000400088 <_start+8>:  lea    (%rsi),%rbx
0x000000000040008b <_start+11>: mov    %rbx,0x8(%rsi)
0x000000000040008f <_start+15>: mov    %rax,0xe(%rsi)
0x0000000000400093 <_start+19>: mov    $0xb,%al
0x0000000000400095 <_start+21>: mov    %rsi,%rbx
0x0000000000400098 <_start+24>: lea    0x8(%rsi),%rcx
0x000000000040009c <_start+28>: lea    0xe(%rsi),%rdx
0x00000000004000a0 <_start+32>: int    $0x80
0x00000000004000a2 <_start+34>: callq  0x400082 <_start+2>
0x00000000004000a7 <_start+39>: (bad)  
0x00000000004000a8 <_start+40>: (bad)  
0x00000000004000a9 <_start+41>: imul   $0x414a6873,0x2f(%rsi),%ebp
0x00000000004000b0 <_start+48>: rex.B
0x00000000004000b1 <_start+49>: rex.B
0x00000000004000b2 <_start+50>: rex.B
0x00000000004000b3 <_start+51>: rex.B
0x00000000004000b4 <_start+52>: rex.B
0x00000000004000b5 <_start+53>: rex.WXB
0x00000000004000b6 <_start+54>: rex.WXB
0x00000000004000b7 <_start+55>: rex.WXB
0x00000000004000b8 <_start+56>: rex.WXB
0x00000000004000b9 <_start+57>: rex.WXB
0x00000000004000ba <_start+58>: rex.WXB add    %bpl,(%r14)
End of assembler dump.
```

I compile the code using yasm and ld

yasm -f elf64 sclivro.asm

ld -o sclivro sclivro.o

My OS is Debian 6.0 x64

I have a Intel Celeron processor

I wanted to know why am I getting a seg fault error
and explain to me.

Thanks for your time.

Also the book tells me to follow these steps:

1. Fill EAX with nulls by xoring EAX with itself.
2. Terminate our /bin/sh string by copying AL over the last byte of the
   string. Remember that AL is null because we nulled out EAX in the previ-
   ous instruction. You must also calculate the offset from the beginning of
   the string to the J placeholder.
3. Get the address of the beginning of the string, which is stored in ESI,
   and copy that value into EBX.
4. Copy the value stored in EBX, now the address of the beginning of the
   string, over the AAAA placeholders. This is the argument pointer to the
   binary to be executed, which is required by execve. Again, you need to
   calculate the offset.
5. Copy the nulls still stored in EAX over the KKKK placeholders, using the
   correct offset.
6. EAX no longer needs to be filled with nulls, so copy the value of our
   execve syscall (0x0b) into AL.
7. Load EBX with the address of our string.
8. Load the address of the value stored in the AAAA placeholder, which is a
   pointer to our string, into ECX.
9. Load up EDX with the address of the value in KKKK, a pointer to null.
10. Execute int 0x80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop rsi instruction is getting the address of the string.

You are overwriting a write protected area when you try to put the nul byte after /bin/sh. I'm not sure why this code is supposed to be special: IT just looks like an obfuscated call to execve().

Comment: Well..im just trying to do what it says in the book... i edit my post so you can see what it's telling me to do.. Thanks for answering btw =)

Comment: Yes the immediate cause of the segfault is that the code is trying to modify itself, but it is in read-only memory region. Shellcode is normally put on the stack which is writable (however, nowadays it isn't executable, so that will pose another problem). Also, 64 bit mode has RIP-relative addressing, no need for tricks.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me =) .

I wonder why that book gives me that code tho maybe because its old.
Again thanks for your time.

One more thing... do you know any good books about this? or maybe a website you can refer me too, preferably for x64. Does not have to be about shellcode just something that can explain me things like this.

Answer (score 3):

The shellcode you've posted is for Linux running on a 32bit x86 processor - as can be seen from the use of "int 0x80" as system call instruction.

You've compiled it in 64bit mode, though, and attempted to run that. Which fails at the first memory access, because you're not using the *real* address of the "/bin/sh" string (which is in `RSI`) but only the explicitly truncated lower 32bit of it (since your code explicitly stated `ESI`). The latter is invalid, in 64bit mode, where your stack is somewhere at the upper end `0xffff....(64bit addr)` of the address space.

Comment: so do i have to use rsi instead??? I edit the code so now i use rsi and all 64 bit registers still not working =/
also i added the steps the book tells me to follow

Comment: You also have to port this to the 64bit linux system call mechanism if you insist on assembling it as a 64bit program. That's much more work. It should be possible, though, to simply compile / run it as 32bit executable.

Comment: Also, what's the value in `RSI` as reported by gdb on the crash (`info registers` should tell you) ?

Comment: i compiled it as you suggested
yasm -f elf Name.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o Name Name.o
but still getting seg fault at  mov %al,0x7(%esi)
the value in esi after i compiled it for 32bit is
esi            0x8048081 134512769

Comment: @Renato: see Richard's answer.

Comment: See above; `0x8048081` is indeed a location within program text (code), and yasm makes that writeprotected by default (it's not the "classical" default for 32bit x86 text segments). Add an explicit `section .text write` to the beginning of your file to get that back.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help.  I am gonna ask you the same thing i asked Richard Pennington now... do you know any good books about this? or maybe a website you can refer me too, preferably for x64. Does not have to be about shellcode just something that can explain me things like this. Again Thanks for your time =)